# making a url Request ending with an %-Sign

Tags: swift, xcode6

My url Request is like "http://www.heriam.com/gms.setvalue%20dim100%"
and i use Alamofire for the Request

Tha APP chrashed with **fatal error: unexpextendly found nil while unwrapping an Optional Value**

```
          Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://www.heriam.com/gms.setvalue%20dim100%")
                .authenticate(usingCredential: credential)
                .response {(request, response,string, error) in
                    println(response)

         }
```

The problem is the last %! If i leave it all is fine an the Request works.

do you have an idea sending a Request ending with an %???

Comment: That URL is illegal so why would you want to do that? Percent signs are for percent-escaping. If you want to _represent_ a percent sign in a URL, you must percent-escape the percent sign.

Answer (score 0):

You have to prepare your link before converting it to url using stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding. Besides that NSURL method might return nil so you should use if let to unwrap the optional result as follow:

```
let link = "http://www.heriam.com/gms.setvalue%20dim100%"
if let linkWithPercentEscape = link.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
    if let url = NSURL(string: linkWithPercentEscape)  {
        println(url)
    }
}
```